# Android - onScroll Gesture Detector

Tags: android, gesture, gesturedetector, onscroll

I want to implement onScroll, when scroll event occurs.
However I don't understand how can I detect the scroll from bottom up with the parameters that I receive with onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY).

I would be happy to get some guidelines how to implement it or some examples.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use the `distanceY` parameter to determine whether the view was scrolled up or down. `distanceY` represents the distance along the Y axis that has been scrolled since the last call to `onScroll()`. If the value of `distanceY` is greater than zero, the view has been scrolled from a lower position on the Y axis to a higher position on the Y axis.

```
@Override
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
    if (distanceY > 0) {
        // Scrolled upward
        if (e2.getAction() = MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            // The pointer has gone up, ending the gesture
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Note: I have not tested if the `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` will solve your need to check when scrolling has ended, but it seems practical in theory. Also note that technically the gesture could also end if the `MotionEvent`'s action is set to `MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do I need to consider the motion events?  What do they contribute?

Comment: The `MotionEvent`s contain much more fine grain data on the movement being executed such as touch state. `e1` is the first down motion event that started the scrolling (this usually stays constant during the scroll) while `e2` is the move motion event that triggered the current `onScroll`. You can call `getY` on both motion events to calculate the change in Y, but `distanceY` should be able to more simply provide you the same solution.

Comment: Great, I understand. Thank you !

Comment: How can I detect that the scroll is ended? Because the method called multiple times during the scroll.

Comment: I have not tested this, but one way to know if scrolling has ended is by checking if `e2`'s current action is `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`. This assumes that scrolling ends when the touch that initiated the scroll is released. I.e. the pointer is no longer touching the screen. I'll update my answer to give you a code example of what that might look like.

Comment: That would be great! Thanks.

Comment: Tried to do as you said, unfortunately it is not working.

Comment: Doubt it will be useful to you, but most likely to future readers; `onScroll` is called while scrolling, `onFling` is called once the finger is lifted.

Comment: in onScroll, e2 never has MotionEvent.ACTION_UP action. it ends with ACTION_MOVE